# How do I generate database tables in Grails?

Tags: java, mysql, grails

I have an error that I can’t seem to figure out. I am new to Grails and I am trying to get tables into my database. I created the database in MySQL. Then I tried to create tables, but when I start the app and click on the tables I get the following error:

```
/racetrack/race/list
Class org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
Message Table "RACE" not found;
```

My DevelopmentDataSource.groovy file is as follows:

```
class DevelopmentDataSource {
    boolean pooling = true
    String dbCreate = "update"
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/racetrack_dev"
    String driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    String username = "ironmantis7x"
    String password = "mantismonk07"
}
```

I checked in MySQL, and the database exists, but it doesn't have any tables. There should be two — `race` and `registration`. How do I remedy this? Please let me know what other parts of my Grails app you need to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the ancient first edition of *Getting Started With Grails*. That syntax isn’t supported in current Grails versions. Use the second edition, which you can get [here](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started). That’s fairly dated but will work much better.

And for only ~$30, you can get the most recently released Grails book, which covers [Grails 2.0+](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430243775). It was written by two of the core Grails developers, Jeff Brown and Graeme Rocher.

Comment: Thanks... just ordered them both!!

Answer (score 0):

You have not given Grails your MySQL port number:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack?autoreconnect=true"
```

Check the name of your database in MySQL and in your `DataSource.groovy` URL.

If you create a database named `racetrack` in MySQL, your datasource code should look like this:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "ironmantis7x"
    password = "mantismonk07"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack?autoreconnect=true"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can omit the port when it's the default value (3306).

Comment: when I try the above code, I get the following error:  | Error 2013-01-08 08:33:51,793 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps:

Comment: what version of grails do you use? Can you just share your bootstrap code?